# How to change or set cookie value with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

[name of cookie "NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTl1s.png)

And question, how can i change value of this cookie from "ru" to another? for example to "fr" or "kk".

And i should use the angularJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$cookies` dependency injection to achieve this.
There's also a ngCookie provider in angular JS 1.x

See usage above: (put and get methods)

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

Comment: I tried this example, but it did not help. front-end of my project doesn't work, when i use this

Comment: @YerassylToktagazin To Be able to use it, you need to use AngularJS Cookie Modules, you can't use without importing it, see more https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies#!